# Gsheets Query Importrange not giving expected results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm having an issue with the Query(Importrange) function of Google Sheets.

I'm using the following formula

`=Query(IMPORTRANGE('Importrangelink,"'Sheetname'!X1:AA130"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 = 'No'")`

This works however if I extend the selection to AA131 (There is Data in AA131) then all I get returned are the headers. Alternatively if I instead of inputting X1:AA130 , put X:AA then again all I get are the headers.

Would someone know why this is as I have another sheet with this formula requesting the full columns and it works as expected

`=Query(IMPORTRANGE('Importrangelink',"'Sheetname'!A:F"),"select * where Col6 = 'Yes'")`

Comment: Welcome. Sorry to be pedantic but would you please advise whether (in your formulas): is the `importlink` between single quotes or double quotes; is the range (including sheet name) between single quotes or double quotes; what is the value in cell AA131?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importrange with query not working properly](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115521/importrange-with-query-not-working-properly)

Comment: It is always difficult to assess a problem sight-unseen. Details matter. However, I do notice that range in the formula you report works find starts simply with "A:" while the problematic formula starts with "X1:" (instead of simply "X:"). I suggest changing "X1" to "X"; and if that does not resolve the issue, try adding the headers parameter to the QUERY (i.e., a comma and digit 1 after the select ending quote and before the QUERY closing parenthesis). If you still find nothing is working, I encourage you to share a link with permissions "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."